# Using $(this).(".className") to access a specific instance of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of divs that have a person's name on them. When I click a button on the name, I want to create a modal that will use their name. The way I have it formatted right now, it pulls all of the names because they share a class. It's impractical for me to create id's to get a specific name. Is there a way to access the specific name using something like `$(this).$(".memberName").text()`?

Here's my full code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#unmatched .nameCard').on("click", ".btn", function(event) {
    var memberName = $(".memberName").text();
    $("#pairDialog").append(memberName + "?")
  });
});
```

```css
.nameCard {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 100, 171, .5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin: 2px 1px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.nameCard h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 5px 0 3px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
}

#yesBtn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(46, 195, 1, .6);
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid matchBoxes" id="unmatched">
  <div class="nameCard preClick">
    <h2 class="memberName">Jane Doe</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="yesBtn" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pairModal">Submit</button>
  </div>

  <div class="nameCard preClick">
    <h2 class="memberName">John Deere</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="yesBtn" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pairModal">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Pairing Modal -->
<div id="pairModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Ready to Pair?</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="pairDialog">Are you sure you want to pair </p>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Pair</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Never Mind</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: After looking at your JSFiddle, what you want is: `var memberName = $(this).siblings(".memberName").text();` - This in mind, you'll probably want to reconsider your use of `.append()` - perhaps replace the dialog text instead of adding to it, otherwise you'll end up adding the `memberName` again with each button click.

Comment: $(this).prev(".memberName").text();  http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ujghxdup/3/

Comment: Fantastic! Both of those work, thank you!! I tried $(this).parent().siblings(".memberName").text in the past and that didn't work

Comment: As some clarity, `.parent().siblings(".memberName")` wouldn't find anything because the parent has no siblings by that class name. The reason `$(this).siblings(".memberName")` works is because `.memberName` is on the same level as the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `event.delegateTarget` to identify the clicked element's parent, and run your code accordingly.

Also, remember to switch `.append()` with `.html()` or `.text()`, since you won't want to add text forever:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#unmatched .nameCard').on("click", ".btn", function(event) {
        var parent = event.delegateTarget;
        var memberName = $(".memberName", parent).text();

        var currentText = $("#pairDialog").text();
        $("#pairDialog").text(currentText + memberName + "?")
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#unmatched .nameCard').on("click", ".btn", function(event) {
        var card = $(this).closest('.nameCard');
        var memberName = $(".memberName", card).text();
        $("#pairDialog").append(memberName + "?")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery 'siblings' selector as mentioned below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#unmatched .nameCard').on("click", ".btn", function(event) {
     var memberName = $(this).siblings(".memberName").text();
     $("#pairDialog").append(memberName + "?")
    });
 });
```